# VB.Net Masktextbox allow only numbers and two decimals

Tags: vb.net, maskedtextbox

I am looking for a way to create a masktextbox with a custom mask to allow only numbers and decimals. There can only be 2 decimal places & only one decimal point in place. Can this be done from a custom mask. I read the [MSDN Doc related to mask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) but it doesn't seem to allow much flexibility or may be I am missing something, any details in this regard will be helpful.

Input for the mask textbox can be any number followed by 2 decimals (Optional).

Eg. 1200 or 1200.25 or 10

Comment: show your code ?? or what will be your input for `MaskTextBox` ?

Comment: pls check the edited question. thnkx

Comment: You really need `MaskTextBox` for this or a `TextBox` with some code to allow only decimals and numbers on `textbox_keypress` ??

Comment: I thought of using mask textbox because these may be built-in. And keypress or keydown events allows copy & pasting invalid inputs, so this looked liked the ideal solution.